# LIMIT в QuerySet

Tags: python-3.x, django

Можно ли LIMITом вернуть QuerySet, а не список?

```
>>> User.objects.filter(gender='male')[::2]

[<User: sdfsdf>, <User: Jack>, <User: Pavel>]
```

Comment: так фильтр `QuerySet` возвращает же...

Comment: `User.objects.filter(gender='male')[:2]` - без шага вернёт queryset

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, если указать шаг в срезе, то queryset будет вычислен

Comment: А зачем вообще `QuerySet` Вам?